# Google maps marker with user location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have 2 functions, one uses an entered postcode to place a marker on the google maps, the other gets the users location.

I am stuck with how i am meant to get the users location to appear on the map, can anyone help?

Thanks!

//EDIT

Currently entering a postcode works fine, it appears on the map with the specified location, however on click of USE MY LOCATION i want the map to be updated with a marker that uses the users location

//What i am trying to replicate

[image: What i am trying to replicate]

//What i currently have

[image: What i currently have]

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {
      lat: 53.47282,
      lng: -2.24651
    }
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('postcode-box').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

}



var getUserLocation = document.getElementById("use-location");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
      showPosition(location);
    });
  } else {
    getUserLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  padding: .5em;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="Header">
    <div class="header-text">
      <h1>Find a motorcycle dealership</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-text header-text__sub-header-text">
      <h1>Please enter a postcode, address or location and press search to find the colest dealership.</h1>
    </div>



    <div class="postcode-lookup">
      <input id="postcode-box" type="text" class="postcode-input" placeholder="Enter Postcode" />
      <div class="button" id="search">Search</div>
      <div class="button" id="use-location" onclick="getLocation()">Use my location</div>
    </div>


  </div>



  <div class="RightCol ">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some more details? What specifically are you having issues with?

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see that you are only centering the viewpoint of the the map to the users location. You are not doing anything to indicate the position anywhere on the map.

You are missing a marker to indicate the position on the map.

```
function showPosition(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
  });
}
```

Here is the [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) documentation for more info, also if you want to add more details to the icon I suggest you try [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

Comment: Thank you for the reply first of all, i tried to copy this in and still having no luck, i will supply my HTML in the updated version now it may give you a better understanding - thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing complete code, here is a working example of your app: https://jsbin.com/folaxih/edit?html,js,output

You were missing the creation of the marker as Franco suggested and some Scope Issues in your code, you could not read any variable map in your functions because of this, move the functions at the end of init map and should be fixed, see example for guidance.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 15,
center: {
  lat: 53.47282,
  lng: -2.24651
}
});
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', 
function() {
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
});
document.getElementById('use-location').addEventListener('click', 
function() {
getLocation();
});
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

} else {
 getUserLocation.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this 
browser.";
}
}
```

Note: i added a listener for "use-location" and take out onClick

Comment: Thank you very much betofarina, it works just as expected - thank you!!!

Comment: glad it helped, if the answer solves your issue i'll suggest to accept the answer